# OpenSSL help needed

Tags: openssl

I am playing with openssl and I almost have a complete and signed key until I get to this step. The command I'm trying to run is:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in C:\Users\alvar\Documents\Security\AlvaRoberts.csr -CA C:\Users\alvar\Documents\Security\CA\AlvaRobertsca.crt -CAkey C:\Users\alvar\Documents\Security\CA\AlvaRobertsca.key -set_serial 1 -out C:\Users\alvar\Documents\Security\AlvaRoberts.crt -addtrust emailProtection -addreject clientAuth -addreject serverAuth -trustout -extfile C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\smime.cnf -extensions smime
```

end result is

```
X509: Use -help for summary.
```

Have I done the coding wrong?

Comment: *Of course* you've done it wrong. Have you considered doing what it suggests? or consulting the documentation?

Comment: I figured it out I dropped the smime.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I re-reviewed the documentation and I deleted the smime commands as sugguested by another article.

Comment: https://www.dalesandro.net/create-self-signed-smime-certificates/

Comment: Make CA Files

openssl genrsa -aes256 -out [Some path to file out like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ca.key] 4096
openssl req -new -key [Some path to file in like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ca.key] -out [some path to file out like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ca.csr]

Comment: Make a user file

openssl genrsa -aes256 -out [Some path to file out like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.key] 4096
openssl req -new -key [Some path to file in like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.key] -out [some path to file out like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.csr]

Comment: Sign with your own CA

openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in [some path to user.csr file in like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.csr] -CA [some path to CA.CRT file in like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ca.csr] -CAkey [Some path to file in like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ca.key] -CAcreateserial -CAserial ca.seq -out [Some path to out file like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.crt] -addtrust emailProtection -addreject clientAuth -addreject serverAuth -trustout

Comment: Cont    openssl pkcs12 -export -in [location of user crt file C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.crt -inkey [location of key file C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.key] -out [destination of file output C:\Users\Admin\Documents\user.p12]

Comment: Smime data if needed

openssl genrsa -des3 -out [Some path to file out like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\smime.key] 4096

openssl req -new -key [Some path to file in like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\smime.key] -out [some path to file out like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\smime.csr]

Comment: Cont
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in smime.csr -CA [Some path to cacsr file like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Yourca.crt] -CAkey [Some path to your cakey file like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Yourca.key] -CAcreateserial -CAserial ca.seq -out C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Security\output\Adminoberts1smime.crt -setalias "Self Signed SMIME" -addtrust emailProtection -addreject clientAuth -addreject serverAuth -trustout

Comment: Cont openssl pkcs12 -export -in [Path to export your smime crt file like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Yoursmime.crt -inkey [Path to your smime key file like C:\Users\Admin\Documents\smime.key] -out [Path to export your new p12 fileC:\Users\Admin\Documents\smime.p12]

Comment: in text file it all looks nicer